# image mapster attribute repeatation

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemapster

i use image mapster for mapping an  image. when part of area is cliked then another mapping image is come.so i use many image and for every image i need to repeating mapster attribute.i try some way but then onclick function and tooltip is not working.here is my jquery for two image`

```
        $('#man').mapster({
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            mapKey: 'alt',
            fillColor: "000000",
            listKey: 'alt',
            scaleMap: false,
            stroke: true,          
            singleSelect: true,
            toolTipClose: ["tooltip-click", "area-click", "area-mouseout"],
            showToolTip: true,
            onClick: function (e) {
                if (e.key === 'leg') {
                    $('#MaleLegDIV').show();
                    $('#DefaultMaleDIV').hide();
                }
            },
            areas: [
            {
                key: "leg",
                toolTip: 'LEG'
            }
            ]
        });
        $('#manLeg').mapster({
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            mapKey: 'alt',
            fillColor: "000000",
            listKey: 'alt',
            scaleMap: false,
            stroke: true,           
            strokeColor: "3320FF",
            singleSelect: true,
            toolTipClose: ["tooltip-click", "area-click", "area-mouseout"],
            showToolTip: true, 
            areas: [
            {
                key: "toes",
                toolTip: 'TOES'
            },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>`
```

as u see mapster attributes are repeating for every image. so is there any way where i just import the attributes.so many line not need to be write.
any help is appreciate and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i find solution.here is my solution:

```
 var options =
               {
                   fillOpacity: 0.5,
                   mapKey: 'alt',
                   fillColor: "000000",
                   listKey: 'alt',
                   scaleMap: false,
                   stroke: true, 
                   singleSelect: true,
                   toolTipClose: ["area-mouseout"],
                   showToolTip: true,
                   render_highlight: {
                       fade: false
                   }
               };

           $('#man').mapster($.extend({}, options,{

               onClick: function (e) {
                   if (e.key === 'leg') {
                       $('#MaleLegDIV').show();
                       $('#DefaultMaleDIV').hide();
                   }
               },
               areas: [
               {
                   key: "leg",
                   toolTip: 'LEG'
               },
               ]

           }));
```